# Why does gcc report "implicit declaration of function ‘round’"?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

I have the following C code:

```
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    double mydouble = 100.0;
    double whatever = round(mydouble);

    return (int) whatever;
}
```

When I compile this, I get the warnings:

```
round_test.c: In function ‘main’:
round_test.c:6: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘round’
round_test.c:6: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘round’
```

I'm rusty with C, but I thought that the #include  brought a declaration for round() into scope. I've checked my ANSI standard (C99 is the only copy I have) which confirms that the round() function exists in the math.h header. What am I missing here?

Edit: The compiler is GCC 4.3.2 on Ubuntu (intrepid, IIRC). Running gcc -E gives:

```
$ gcc -E round_test.c | grep round
# 1 "round_test.c"
# 1 "round_test.c"
# 2 "round_test.c" 2
    double whatever = round(mydouble);
```

so the definition obviously isn't being found in the headers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I see you're using gcc.

By default, gcc uses a standard similar to C89. You may want to "force" it to use the C99 standard (the parts it complies with)

```
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic ...
```

Quote from [GCC Manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.4/gcc/Standards.html#Standards)

> By default, GCC provides some
>   extensions to the C language that on
>   rare occasions conflict with the C
>   standard. See Extensions to the C
>   Language Family. Use of the -std
>   options listed above will disable
>   these extensions where they conflict
>   with the C standard version selected.
>   You may also select an extended
>   version of the C language explicitly
>   with -std=gnu89 (for C89 with GNU
>   extensions) or -std=gnu99 (for C99
>   with GNU extensions). The default, if
>   no C language dialect options are
>   given, is -std=gnu89; this will change
>   to -std=gnu99 in some future release
>   when the C99 support is complete. Some
>   features that are part of the C99
>   standard are accepted as extensions in
>   C89 mode.

Comment: Thanks, -std=c99 seemed to solve it. I hadn't realised round() was a C99 addition (and of course all my references are C99 and neglect to mention this)

Comment: (surprised look) Is round() really a C99 addition?

Comment: Right, C89 didn't describe the `round()` function (of course compilers could provide it as an extension).

Comment: Looks like it - from the Ubuntu 8.04 manpage - 
       round(), roundf(), roundl(): _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600 || _ISOC99_SOURCE; or cc -std=c99

Comment: Also need -lm to link libm to get the actual function.

Comment: @Tim: if you want a text-only version of the C89 Standard look @ http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt

Comment: Had a similar issue (3 years later...) and this was the solution. I wouldn't have guessed that the solution was to force C99. Good advice. +1

Answer (score 3):

Something must be wrong with your gcc installation, system headers, or compilation options.

Try compiling with -E. That will show you what the preprocessor output -- including which headers are being included and what's in them.  On my Ubuntu Linux system it's about 1000 lines of output, including this:

```
extern double round (double __x) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__)) __attribute__ ((__const__));
```

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic). Here `#include <math.h>` loads /usr/include/math.h which loads /usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h which contains the declaration.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell gcc that you want C99, and that you want to link in libm:

```
gcc -std=c99 -lm round_test.c
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you type compiles cleanly on MacOS X 10.5.8 with GCC 4.0.1.  If prodded with options '-Wall -Wextra', it complains about unused parameters argc and argv - not material.

Have you looked in `<math.h>` on your machine?

Have you tried with options such as '-stc=c99'?

Answer (score 0):

C99 was the answer, but the full story is a little more complicated. The reason I'd been playing with this at all was that I was trying to compile a library written for Windows, which had its own "optimised" definition of round(). I got a linker error telling me that the definition conflicted with the built-in, so I removed the definition (and declaration). Once I'd done that I started to get the "implicit declaration error".

It seems that the default compile mode (without the -std=c99 flag) is neither conforming C89 nor C99: if it were conforming C89, you should be able to provide a custom definition of round() without conflicting, and if it were conforming C99 the declaration should be in math.h.

Comment: The default mode is `-std=gnu89` :)

Answer (score -2):

you need to link with the math library. So when you compile, be sure to add the `-lm` flag.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but this is a compile problem, not a link problem. I realised I left out my compiler command (my bad), but I was compiling with gcc -c.