# C using gcc -Wall gives an array subscript has type 'char' error

Tags: c, gcc

The following code is a simple postfix calculation program. While The code works perfectly fine without the -Wall option, I can't seem to find why it does not work with the option. I have a vague idea that -Wall does not allow me to use a default signed char array. Hence, according to the error message, `postfix2.c: In function ‘main’: postfix2.c:45:3: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’` I tried declaring `unsigned char input[13]` instead. It did not fix the issue. Any pointer on the concept of -Wall, as well as where the error might be? Thank you. Oh and allow me to correct the code myself by not simply giving me the fixed code!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE

int stack[100];
int top;

void push(int x){
  top++;
    stack[top] = x;
}

int pop(){
    int temp = stack[top];
    top--;
    return(temp);
}

int main()
{
    char input[13];
    int integer, a, b, result;

    while(1){
        scanf("%s", input);

        if (isdigit(input[0])) {
            integer = atoi(input);
            push(integer);
        }

        if (input[0] == '+'){
            b = pop();
            a = pop();
            push (a+b);
        }
        else{
            if (input[0] == '-'){
                b = pop();
                a = pop();
                push (a-b);
            }
            else{
                if (input[0] == '*'){
                    b = pop();
                    a = pop();
                    push (a*b);
                }
            }
        }

        if (input[0] == 'p'){
            result = pop();
            printf("%d\n", result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't the real code.

Comment: first, provide the real code

Comment: I see the code that I pasted. Do you guys not see the code? Should I post a gist link instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [array subscript has type 'char'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186219/array-subscript-has-type-char)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this:

`if (isdigit(input[0]))`

to:

`if (isdigit((unsigned char)input[0]))`

or

`if (isdigit((int)input[0]))`

for more details see similar question: [array subscript has type 'char'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186219/array-subscript-has-type-char)

Comment: worked perfectly. thank you. I didn't think of casting to prevent the negative index

Comment: it's the mess of c macro's and isdigit() to be more specific, they are not warning-friendly to say the least

Answer (score 1):

This means that the index for the array can be negative.

This can be a problem as a char could represent a signed value, and you may be requesting a negative index.